# Undefined method 'getArticulos'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Tags: php, symfony

En mi proyecto de Symfony 3 borré la carpeta Entity, dentro de un Bundle, pero cuando vuelvo a generar las mismas entidades de la misma base de datos me aparece este error:

> Undefined method 'getArticulos'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - BadMethodCallException
>
> Stack Trace
>
> ```
> in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php at line 226  -
>                     break;
>                 default:
>                     throw new \BadMethodCallException(
>                         "Undefined method '$method'. The method name must start with ".
>                         "either findBy or findOneBy!"
>                     );
> at EntityRepository ->__call ('getArticulos', array())
> in src\AppBundle\Controller\ProductosController.php at line 24  +
> at ProductosController ->listarAction (object(Request))
> at call_user_func_array (array(object(ProductosController), 'listarAction'), array(object(Request)))
> in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 139  +
> at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
> in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 62  +
> at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
> in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php at line 169  +
> at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
> in web\app_dev.php at line 30  +
> ```

Logs  -
1 error

```
INFO - Matched route "productosBEListar".
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception BadMethodCallException: "Undefined method 'getArticulos'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!" at C:\xampp\htdocs\2018\tienda\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php line 226
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Dice que el error está en ProductosController.php, línea 24, pero no veo nada raro.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use BDBundle\Entity\Articulos;
use BDBundle\Entity\ArticulosRepository;

class ProductosController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) { {
            return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:productos.html.twig');
        }
    }

    public function listarAction(Request $request) { {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $articulos = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")
                    ->getArticulos();

            $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
            $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                    $articulos, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 5);

            return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:productos_listar.html.twig', array(
                        'pagination' => $pagination
                            //Mostrar los datos por pantalla, para comprobar si devuelven un valor
                            // var_dump($fabricantes)
            ));
        }
    }

    public function insertarAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $fabricantes = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Fabricantes")->findAll();
        //libro vacío
        $articulo = new Articulos();
        //le asigno la primera categoria y editorial al libro vacío
        //para evitar ERROR EN LA SELECT
        $fabricante = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Fabricantes")->find(1);
        $articulo->setCodFabricante($fabricante);

        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
            //0-. Regoger DATOS DEL POST
            //$codArticulo = $request->get('codArticulo');
            // El nombre del get debe ser el mismo que hay en la entidad
            $nombreArticulo = $request->get('articuloArticulos');
            $codArticulo = $request->get('codArticuloArticulos');
            $precioVenta = $request->get('precioVentaArticulos');
            $precioCosto = $request->get('precioCostoArticulos');
            $existencias = $request->get('existenciasArticulos');
            $categoria = $request->get('categoriaArticulos');
            $peso = $request->get('pesoArticulos');
            $logo = $request->get('logoArticulos');

            //RECOGO LOS ID DE LAS FORANEAS
            $codFabricante = $request->get('codFabricanteArticulos');
            //BUSCO LOS OBJETOS RELACIONADOS

            $fabricante = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Fabricantes")->find($codFabricante);

            $articulo = new Articulos(); //crear un OBJETO --> REGISTRO
            $articulo->setArticulo($nombreArticulo);
            //$articulo->setCodArticulo($codArticulo);
            $articulo->setPrecioVenta($precioVenta);
            $articulo->setPrecioCosto($precioCosto);
            $articulo->setExistencias($existencias);
            $articulo->setCategoria($categoria);
            $articulo->setPeso($peso);
            $articulo->setLogo($logo);

            //$libro->setImagen('symfony.jpg');
            //asignAR LOS OBEJTOS RELACIONADOS
            $articulo->setCodFabricante($fabricante);



            // var_dump($libro);
            //persistir
            $em->persist($articulo);
            //graba
            $flush = $em->flush();
            echo $flush;
        }
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:productos_insertar.html.twig', array(
                    'fabricantes' => $fabricantes,
                    'articulo' => $articulo));
    }

    public function actualizarAction(Request $request) {

        $codArticulo = $request->get('codArticulo');
        $fabricante = $request->get('codFabricante');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $articulo = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")->find($codArticulo);

        $fabricantes = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Fabricantes")->findAll();

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:productos_insertar.html.twig', array(
                    'fabricantes' => $fabricantes,
                    'articulo' => $articulo));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu funcion `listarAction` tienes:

```
           `$articulos = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")
               ->getArticulos();`
```

Y deberia ser:

```
$articulos = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")->findAll();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era problema